# How to put marchex call tracking script within conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to put the marchex call tracking script in the footer section of the site only if cookie is set,but the site is in square space and i can only use javascript/jquery . I have tried the following code but it seems not triggering, means the number changing is not working.

```
    <script>
window.onload = function () { 
if(getCookiee("cpc")!="1" && getCookiee("fb")!="1" )
{
vs_account_id = "xxxxxxxxxx";
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "https://rw1.marchex.io/euinc/number-changer.js";
$("body").append(s);
}
}
</script>
```

The actual script is :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
vs_account_id      = "xxxxxxxx";
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rw1.marchex.io/euinc/number-changer.js">
</script>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```js
var vs_account_id = "xxxxxxxxxx";

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if(getCookie("cpc") != '' && getCookie('fb') != '') {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "https://rw1.marchex.io/euinc/number-changer.js";
        body.append(s);
    }
});
```

It is vanilla javascript without jQuery.